# DOMContentLoaded is being called twice when using a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, domcontentloaded

I am including a module on my page with the following tag:

`<script src = "js/manage.js" type = "module"></script>`

In that module I am adding an event listener for DOMContentLoaded with the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOM Content Loaded');
  init();
}, {"once":true});
```

The problem is that the DOMContentLoaded event is firing twice and my init function is being called twice. I added a `console.log()` to the `init` function so I can see when it is called/where it's being called from, too. This is what I see in Chrome's JS console:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome JS console showing duplicate function calls]

You can see that both are called twice, but in one instances the location is "manage.js" and in the other it's "manage".

I don't think that the issue is with the code that I've shown here, because I've used this same approach for other projects and I've never had this problem. I've tried searching with Google and on SO (that's where I got the idea to add the "once" directive) but so far I can't find any possible reasons for this to be happening.

I also tried replacing the anonymous function in the event listener with just adding init directly, like this:

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, {"once":true});`

But the result was the same (minus the lack of the log entry for the DOMContentLoaded event).

At this point, I am really just looking for some direction for my troubleshooting - I'm at a loss for what to check or where to look next so if anyone has any ideas for what could possibly cause something like this (and also if someone can explain the difference between "manage" and "manage.js" that I'm seeing in the console since I have a hunch that that is related.) I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt the event is firing twice. I suspect you've added the listener twice.

Comment: The log messages mention both `manage` and `manage.js`.

Comment: @Barmar I had thought that, which is why I added the console.log to the anonymous function in the event listener - I only added it to just that and it's showing twice in the console. I only have one file named `manage.js` and it's added via the line in the original question, it's not added twice.

Comment: Put `console.log("Adding event listener")` before the call to `window.addEventListener()`. Do you see that twice as well?

Comment: yes, I see it twice before the other items. Once from `manage` and once from `manage.js` just like the others. So, I think that's the issue - somehow there are two versions of the file being included, one with the extension and one without, but I double checked I'm only including it once (with the file extension.)

Comment: Do you have `import from 'manage'` anywhere?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, thank you. I was able to solve this. In another module, I was importing two functions from manage.js using the notation `import { ... } from "./manage";` I changed this to `import { ... } from "./manage.js";` and that solved the issue! Do you know what this is called so I can read more about it/know what causes this? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know what it's called. Modules are only loaded once, but since you loaded it with different names it didn't realize they were the same.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251956/how-does-javascript-import-find-the-module-without-an-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with help from comments from @barmar.

The problem was that, in another module, I was importing two functions from `manage.js`, but I was not specifying the file extension (`.js`). Because I had specified the extension when including the module in the `<script>` tag, the browser was seeing them as two separate files and so was including it twice. By adding the file extension to my `include` directive, it prevented the event listener from being added twice.